# Powershell how to convert to hashmap or 2d array

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashmap

I have a text file containing following data... I want to access them inside powershell ISE as a 2d array or hashmap. how ?

```
key,value
cleanupfolder,70
addfile,80
deletefile,20
millisecond,900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ConvertFrom-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135201) cmdlet:

```
Get-content 'Path-To-Your-File' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Output:

```
key           value
---           -----
cleanupfolder 70   
addfile       80   
deletefile    20   
millisecond   900
```